# Constructor undefined , although I imported them

Tags: android, andengine

```
@Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.scene = new Scene();
```

The constructor Scene() is undefined

```
this.scene.setBackground(new Background(0, 1, 0));
```

The method setBackground(Background) is undefined for the type Scene

```
pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.scene);
```

The method onCreateSceneFinished(Scene) in the type IGameInterface.OnCreateSceneCallback is not applicable for the arguments (Scene)

```
 }


   @Override
   public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback)
```

The method onPopulateScene(Scene, IGameInterface.OnPopulateSceneCallback) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method

```
 throws Exception {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Sprite sPlayer = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2,
                playerTexureRegion, this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        sPlayer.setRotation(45.0f);

        this.mEngine.getScene().attachChild(sPlayer);

        pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't import constructors, you import *classes* and *call* their constructors if you want to create objects of that type.

This

```
this.scene = new Scene();
```

is not allowed as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Scene.html#Scene(android.view.ViewGroup)), you must use one of the provided constructors (read: you have to supply a `ViewGroup` and a `View`).

I would recommend that you revisited some Java basics to actually being able to sort out these kind of 'problems', and to understand the API documentation yourself (e.g. `Scene` clearly has no `setBackground()` method).